# How to output an index while iterating over an array in python

Tags: python

I am iterating over an array in python:

```
for g in [ games[0:4] ]:
    g.output()
```

Can I also initialise and increment an index in that `for` loop and pass it to `g.output()`?

such that `g.output(2)` results in:

```
Game 2 - ... stuff relating to the object `g` here.
```

Comment: try using enumerate() method.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Like this:

```
for index, g in enumerate(games[0:4]):
    g.output(index)
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the built-in [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) method:

```
for i,a in enumerate(['cat', 'dog']):
   print '%s is %d' % (a, i)

# output:
# cat is 0
# dog is 1
```